# I only want to insert data from table2 to table1 that doesn't exist already on MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table named MarketData, and I am trying to pull certain columns from MarketData and insert them to another table called Payups. But I only want to insert data that doesn't repeat onto Payups. 
Keep in mind, the MarketData table includes more columns that I don't need in the PayUps column. 
After I execute the query below, it keeps on adding records that are similar.

```
INSERT INTO [MortgagePipeline].[dbo].[PayUps] 
(
    RecordDate
    ,Investor
    ,Product
    ,MinCoupon
    ,[Payup(bcp)]
)
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ContractDate
    ,t1.SourceCode
    ,t1.ProductName
    ,t1.ContractInterestRate
    ,t1.ContractPrice
FROM [MortgagePipeline].[dbo].[MarketData] t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT RecordDate
        ,Investor
        ,Product
        ,MinCoupon
        ,[Payup(bcp)]
    FROM [MortgagePipeline].[dbo].[PayUps] t2
    WHERE t2.RecordDate = t1.ContractDate
        AND t2.Investor = t1.SourceCode
        AND t2.Product = t1.ProductName
        AND t2.MinCoupon = t1.ContractInterestRate
        AND t2.[Payup(bcp)] = t1.ContractPrice
        AND t2.MaxCoupon = NULL
        AND t2.PayupName = NULL
)
```

RecordDate, Investor , Product ,MinCoupon ,[Payup(bcp)], MaxCoupon  PayupName are all the columns that exists on Payups. all of The values of those columns are inserted from the MarketData Table except from MaxCoupon and PayupName that remain null.

Comment: You have = NULL. Nothing ever equals NULL. You should use IS NULL instead.

Comment: AMAZING! Thank you! 
It is now working

Comment: Do you want to allow duplicates if their MaxCoupon or PayupName  are not null?